# Mock up taging and description cms system

Tags: content-management-system, mockups

I'm looking for a cms system to:
- upload an image like mockup and add and positioning tags(marker) on the image 
- write description for each marker  (multilingual)
- in front end, when we click on each tag, it shows the description of the tag!

Basically I want to use this system to manage the content of the image mockup or the design.

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI prototyping tools like [invision](http://invisionapp.com) or [concept.ly](http://concept.ly) for that . 
I am not sure which of them are multilingual but both of them provide taging and navigation on images .